# Android GCM push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a problem in my push notification, when i click on the notification there is no new  intent starting.
Please help me to fix this issue,
Thanks in advance.

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context,String htitle, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    //String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    String title=htitle;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("head",title);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("desc",message);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

}
```

Comment: You can check this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("head",title);
notificationIntent.putExtra("desc",message);

PendingIntent intent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

In manifest File

```
<activity
    android:name="com.android.testing.MainActivity"
   android:noHistory="true">
</activity>
```

In My App i have use this hope, this ll helps you

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("App Name")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

    Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
```

Comment: Vaishali,
Tried that but still same, no changes :(

Comment: Thank you so much Vaishali,
I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting flags  **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** to notificationIntent

and **PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT** to PendingIntent

```
int iUniqueId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
PendingIntent  Intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, iUniqueId, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Hi john,
What is that iUniqueId?

Comment: IUniqueId will just create unique id when noticaition is created , in your case its variable "when" but you are not using it